# Pushing data to Google Analytics Measurement Protocol via Java - "no data received"

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to report data from an application to Google Analytics using the `Measurement Protocol`.

The application is a desktop application - not web or mobile app etc - I'm aware that Google Analytics isn't the optimal choice for this.

I've created a webstream `Data Stream`, and created a `Measurement Protocol API secret`.

But when I submit data, it's not recorded in Google Analytics - on the stream I see `No data received in past 48 hours`, and the real time dashboard is empty.

I've also tested submitting this using the [Event Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder) but even submitting there doesn't work.

Simple example of what I'm submitting - obviously the correct `measurement_id` and `api_secret` are being used:

```
    System.out.println(HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(
    "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret={API_SECRET}&measurement_id=G-{MEASUREMENT_ID}"))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json").POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("""
        {
          "user_id" : "1116",
          "client_id" : "1116",
          "non_personalized_ads" : false,
          "events" : [ {
            "name" : "select_content",
            "params" : { }
          } ]
        }
                        """)).build(), BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()).statusCode());
```

This returns status code `204`.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: did you check the realitme repports?

Comment: @DalmTo yes I checked the real-time dashboard as per my question

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: @HeelMega no - I moved from `Google Analytics 4` to `Universal Analytics` (it's predecessor) and it works ok now. I *think* part of the problem was that my `client_id` is wrong and instead it needs to come from a cookie.

Comment: @Jakg that is exactly what we ended up doing and yes client_id is the issue